# Text fill with colour CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to implement a text colour fill from left to right using CSS as in the following codepen.io/anon/pen/oYojzZ

However, instead of filling in the text with colour, the background is being filled in. In this example the text colour black should be changing to pink rather than the background.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.tooltiptext {
    position: relative;
}
.popUpWord {
    color: pink;
}
.popUpWordBlack {
    color: black;
}
.outPop {
    margin: auto;
    background: none;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /* Unset our animation play state initially - this will reset the animation when the hover is no longer */
    animation-play-state: unset;
}
/* Since .outPop is hidden we add the style to either when the element is hovered or it's sibling is hovered */
.outPopBlack:hover + .outPop,
.outPop:hover{
    /* Turn our animation on when we are hovering over our element */
    animation: stripes 2s linear 1 forwards;
}
.outPopBlack {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
@keyframes stripes {
    to {
        width: 32px;
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="tooltiptext"> 
  <span class="outPopBlack">
    <span class="popUpWordBlack">hello</span>
  </span>  
  <span class="outPop">
    <span class="popUpWord">hello</span>
  </span>  
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! However I need it to be started on hover. Adding `:hover` to  `.tooltiptext` did not work.

Comment: @Techs The animation now starts on hover. Please look at the notes in the CSS for explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! And is there a way the word can be set to the initial colour on hover out (black in this case)?

Comment: @Techs The animation now resets when it's not being hovered. Please look at the notes in the CSS for explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation :)

Comment: As it currently is, the coloured text is being filled in 2 seconds calculcated on 32px. How can the two seconds be filled in dynamically depending on the length of the word? Thanks